# How to extend a "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" to a given extent

Tags: r, raster, r-sp

I have a shapefile which I would like to extend (basically adding some NA rows and cols). Is there any function which does that like `raster::extend`? Unfortunately this only works for `raster` objects.

I can crop it using `raster::crop`, which has a method for `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, but I am not able to find anything for extending.

Comment: Not a completely satisfactory solution, but I usually find it easier to convert the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame to a regular data frame using `fortify` from `ggplot2`. From there, you could extend the data however you need using regular data frame functions. This also comes with the bonus that the result is easily understood by `ggplot` and its graphical functions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You can easily add NA coluns by directly accessing the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` data slot like this: spdf@data, where spdf is your `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`  object e.g. `spdf@data$my_na` adds a new column called "my_na". As for the "rows", why would you want to add NA rows to an `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object?? If you just want to extend the spatial extent, you could `buffer()` to the extent you want.

Comment: @Shekeine I wanted to use rasetrize function and for that the extent of the two should be the same. The goal was to have the extent of the raster file, I could crop in case the polygon is bigger but could not extend if smaller. My problem is solved since I crop the raster instead and after rasterizing I will extend the raserized raster extend. But it would be nice if I know how to use buffer. My understanding of the word buffer makes me confuse as it should create a buffer around an object by giving a distance.

Comment: `rasterize` doesn't require that the polygon has the same extent as the raster. Did you try `rasterize(p, r)` (for raster `r` and SpatialPolygons* `p`)? What happened?

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to do this!
The extent data of a SpatialPolygons seems to be stored in a slot called bbox. Inside the slot (which you can access via `my.polygon@bbox`), you will find a simple matrix like this one:

```
  min max
x -81 -80
y  11  12
```

Simply replacing that matrix with another one that looks like the one you want to get will change the extent of your SpatialPolygons. You can even use the extent of your other polygon or raster to make the matrix:

```
my.polygon@bbox <- as.matrix(extent(my.raster))
```

It is not as neat as raster's extend... but it works the same :)
Hope it is not too late!